# google apps script that sends sms from spreadsheet data

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm wondering if anyone has already put together a script that simply takes a phone number from a cell and sends a text message.  Just the same as if it were an email address.  Using the carriers email extension is not the solution I'm looking for but if someone has figured out how to programmatically figure out the carrier extension, add it to the phone number, then that would work too.

Example I'm using for sending an email

```
     function inventory() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRowIndex()
  var firstName = sheet.getRange(row, getColIndexByName("First Name")).getValue();
  var lastName = sheet.getRange(row, getColIndexByName("Last Name")).getValue();
  //var phone = sheet.getRange(row, getColIndexByName("Phone Number")).getValue();
  var email = sheet.getRange(row, getColIndexByName("Email Address")).getValue();
  var inventoryLinks = sheet.getRange(row, getColIndexByName("Inventory Links")).getValue();
  //var userEmail = 'put email here';
  var subject = "Your Inventory List";                 
  var body = "Hello"
             + "\n\n" + "Please follow the supplied links below to see the listings that fit your profile."
             + "\n\n" + sheet.getRange(row, getColIndexByName("Inventory Links")).getValue();

  MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {name:"Inventory List"});
}

function getColIndexByName(columnName) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var numColumns = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var row = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, numColumns).getValues();
  for (i in row[0]) {
    var name = row[0][i];
    if (name == columnName) {
      return parseInt(i) + 1;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
```

So I want to accomplish the same thing replacing the email address with a phone number

This is what I ended up with.  Works Great!

```
function sendSMS() {
// Get account SID and auth token here:
//   https://www.twilio.com/user/account
//  Also, you have to buy a paid account to send SMS to any phone number.  Otherwise you can only  send to verified numbers
//  So this script allows me to put my cursor in the row I want to send an SMS.  

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRowIndex();
var phone = sheet.getRange(row, getColIndexByName("Phone")).getValue();
var inventoryLinks = sheet.getRange(row, getColIndexByName("Inventory Links")).getValue();
var sentSMS = sheet.getRange(row, getColIndexByName("Sent SMS")).getValue();
var comments = sheet.getRange(row, getColIndexByName("Comments")).getValue();
var activeUser = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
var extphone = "+1" + phone;
var body = "Click on the link/s to see current inventory.  " + inventoryLinks;
var accountSid = "get it from your Twilio account";
var authToken = "get it from your Twilio account";
var url = "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/" + accountSid + "/SMS/Messages.json";
var options = {
method: "post",
headers: {
  Authorization: "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(accountSid + ":" + authToken)
},
payload: {
  // From is one of your Twilio phone numbers
  From: "Put you Twilio number here",
  To: extphone,
Body: body
}
};

sheet.getRange(row, getColIndexByName("Sent SMS")).setValue('Sent SMS').setComment(new Date() +        activeUser);
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
Logger.log(response);
}
```

Comment: This might interest you.:  https://github.com/entaq/GoogleAppsScript/tree/master/Twilio

Comment: ok, I see that there is an option to receive SMS, but not one for sending.

Comment: See the solution above for what I came up with

Comment: Great!  Thanks :-)  too bad I don't have a similar service in my country...